# Can't change key repeat speed in OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard

I changed key repeat in System Preferences → Keyboard. The Key Repeat slider changed successfully. But actual key repeat speed is just as same as before.

I plugged in several USB keyboards to this Mac. Now I'm using only one USB keyboard, no Bluetooth keyboard connected.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KeyRemap4Macbook was opening and changed repeat speed. So repeat speed in "System Preference" can't work.